# sqlite db update

Tags: android, sqlite

Is there an easy way to update a table in sqlite in android? (like a single line in built method) ? I have a table with few columns and primary is one column. I want to search by the primary key and then update a row in the table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `rawQuery` like this:

```
cur = mDb.rawQuery("update " + TABLE_NAME
+ " set column1=mango where id='" + _id + "'",null);
```

---

where

- `cur` is *`Cursor`* object
- `TABLE_NAME` is *`NAME OF THE TABLE`*
- `_id` is *`name of the column`* (only example)

Comment: Thanks I used this. :) Thanks a lot for the help mate! :)

Comment: Avoid using error-prone syntax by using string.format to build your query i.e `String.format("update %s set column1=%s where id='%s'",TABLE_NAME,"mango",_id)` @Waqas answer is more correct as it allows for a variable number of fields to be updated without altering the code.

Answer (score 13):

To use with predefined **update** method from android, use it as below:

```
ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
args.put("col_name", "new value");

db.update("table_name", args, String.format("%s = ?", "primary_column"),
           new String[]{"primary_id"});
```

Or to run as a single line, go with this (not recommended):

```
db.execSQL("UPDATE table_name SET col_name='new_value' WHERE
           primary_column='primary_id'");
```

Answer (score 6):

Read the documentation for [SQLiteDatabase.update](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues%29)

You should end up with something like this:

`affected = db.update(TABLE_NAME, values, where, whereArgs);`

**UDPATE**

Avoid raw queries using error-prone syntax at all costs.  I see a lot of answers here that use a lot of `'"' + SOMETHING + "'"` ... this is extremely bad practice and you will spend all your time looking for errors on places that are hard to find or simply a complete waste of time.

If you must use raw queries, try forming them with String.format to avoid perilous debug sessions and migraines.

Comment: plus one for the Update. Always prefer the db.update() method instead of the manual raw query. Trying to store a json that contains an apostrophe will convince you too

Answer (score 1):

Then you should already know what's your primary key.

```
dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
ContentValues values = createContentValues(profileVo);
db.update(ProfileVO.TABLE_NAME, values, ProfileVO.COLUMN_ID + "=" + profile.getId(), null)
```

Here's a good tutorial for you http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:

http://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html

and

[SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(...)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public void updateFunction(int id) {
            String updateStmnt  = "UPDATE  YOUR_TABLE SET YOUR_COLUMN = "
                    + id;
            database.execSQL(updateStmnt);
        }
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: Consider using string.format instead of `+` for strings ... it's much more legible and less error-prone

Answer (score 0):

Using `database.update` make it simple like this:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_NAME, name);
    values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_JOB, job);
    values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_DATE_START, date_start);
    database.update(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_EMPLOYEES, values, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID+"="+id, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this a bit old, but in case anyone needed another way:

```
public boolean updateNote(Note note) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = notesDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(NotesDbContract.NoteEntry._ID, note.getId());
    contentValues.put(NotesDbContract.NoteEntry.COLUMN_NAME_TITLE, note.getTitle());
    contentValues.put(NotesDbContract.NoteEntry.COLUMN_NAME_DSECRIPTION, note.getDescription());

    int result = db.update(NotesDbContract.NoteEntry.TABLE_NAME,
            contentValues,
            NotesDbContract.NoteEntry._ID + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(note.getId())}
    );
    db.close();

    return result > 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but what is another way and why `db.close();`?

Comment: @CoolMind I recommend using the result to get a return flag about our delete command success, so we can decide how to navigate the code flow based on it, for ex refresh a view to hold the new values.