# add individual items to a row in a db android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

i have four items name, age , sex, dob. I have four different activities and i want to insert each item into the same row with the same row id but using different activities. So the first activity will insert name the next activity age and so on.
Thats how i can insert all the data with one activity.

```
public long createEntry( String name, String age,String sex, String dob) throws SQLException{
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put(KEY_NAME, name);
            cv.put(KEY_AGE, age);
            cv.put(KEY_SEX, sex);
            cv.put(KEY_DATE, dob);

            return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
            }
```

But how do i insert each item into the same row in seperate activities? i am new to this?

Comment: First you create the row using `insert()`, after that you must call `update()` i each activity to modify a particular item in the existing row

Comment: can you provide me a link showing an example of how you do this as i am still confused on how to employ your advice

Comment: For the `insert()` you must fill in valid values according to the table creation statement. If `NULL` values are allowed you can used these. For the `update()` you can e.g. look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10978136/sqlite-db-update