# database records not updating android studio , sql-lite

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio

Could someone help me? my records are not updating.
I guess the edittext stay the same but not too sure.

How to change the view values that is being put in the edittext to change to the values in updating edittexts.
Would appreciate some help with this
Thank you.

DatabaseManager

```
   public Cursor selectRow(String ID) {
        String query = "Select * from " + TABLE_NAME + " where studentID = " + ID;
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        return cursor;

    }

    public boolean updateData(String id, String fn, String ln, String ge, String cs, String a, String loc) {
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("studentID", id);
        contentValues.put("first_name", fn);
        contentValues.put("last_name", ln);
        contentValues.put("gender", ge);
        contentValues.put("course_study", cs);
        contentValues.put("age", a);
        contentValues.put("location", loc);
        db.update(TABLE_NAME, contentValues, "studentID = ?", new String[]{id});

        return true;
    }
```

The above is parts of my database that I use in this activity.

activity main.java

```
 private void UpdateData() {
                              u.setOnClickListener(
                                      new View.OnClickListener() {
                                          @Override
                                          public void onClick(View v) {
                                              uptable.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                              again.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                            Cursor res = mydManager.selectRow(text);


                            if (res != null && res.moveToFirst()) {
                                String id = Integer.toString(res.getInt(0));
                                String nme = res.getString(1);
                                String lnme = res.getString(2);
                                String gen = res.getString(3);
                                String corse = res.getString(4);
                                String ag = Integer.toString(res.getInt(5));
                                String lo = res.getString(6);
                                studid.setText(id);
                                fname.setText(nme);
                                lname.setText(lnme);
                                gender.setText(gen);
                                course.setText(corse);
                                age.setText(ag);
                                loc.setText(lo);

                            }


                        }
                    }
            );
        }


        public void UpdateData1() {
            again.setOnClickListener(
                    new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            uptable.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            String id = studid.getText().toString();
                            String nme = fname.getText().toString();
                            String lnme = lname.getText().toString();
                            String gen = gender.getText().toString();
                            String corse = course.getText().toString();
                            String ag = age.getText().toString();
                            String lo = loc.getText().toString();
                            boolean isUpdated = mydManager.updateData(id, nme , lnme, gen, corse ,ag , lo);
                            if (isUpdated == true)
                                Toast.makeText(Main4Activity.this, "Data Updated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                            else
                                Toast.makeText(Main4Activity.this, "Data Not Updated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
            );
        }
```

I tried having a button to set the data but it still stays the same.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10978136/sqlite-db-update

Answer (score 1):

Sorry din't read the code, take the sample if it helps
Just the logic..

```
public long updateNote(NoteModel noteModel) {
    if (LOG_DEBUG) UtilLogger.showLogUpdate(TAG, noteModel, noteModel.getRow_pos());
    long updatedRow = 0;

    try {

        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(DBSchema.DB_TITLE, noteModel.getTitle());
        contentValues.put(DBSchema.DB_IMAGE_PATH, noteModel.getImgUriPath());
        contentValues.put(DBSchema.DB_SUB_TEXT, noteModel.getSub_text());
        contentValues.put(DBSchema.DB_CREATE_DATE, noteModel.getCreateDate());
        contentValues.put(DBSchema.DB_UPDATE_DATE, noteModel.getUpdateDate());
        contentValues.put(DBSchema.DB_SCHEDULED_TIME_LONG, noteModel.getScheduleTimeLong());
        contentValues.put(DBSchema.DB_SCHEDULED_TIME_WHEN, noteModel.getScheduledWhenLong());
        contentValues.put(DBSchema.DB_SCHEDULED_TITLE, noteModel.getScheduledTitle());
        contentValues.put(DBSchema.DB_IS_ALARM_SCHEDULED, noteModel.getIsAlarmScheduled());
        contentValues.put(DBSchema.DB_IS_TASK_DONE, noteModel.getIsTaskDone());
        contentValues.put(DBSchema.DB_IS_ARCHIVED, noteModel.getIsArchived());


        updatedRow = mSqLiteDatabase.updateWithOnConflict(
                DBSchema.DB_TABLE_NAME,
                contentValues,
                DBSchema.DB_ROW_ID + " =?", new String[]{String.valueOf(noteModel.get_id())}, mSqLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);

        return updatedRow;

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return updatedRow;
}
```

then take the cursor

```
public Cursor getCursorForAlarmScheduled(String passAlarmScheduledStatus) {
    if (LOG_DEBUG)
        Log.w(TAG, " pick all record with alarmScheduled 1  : " + passAlarmScheduledStatus);
    return mSqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(DBSchema.DB_SELECT_ALL +
            " WHERE " + DBSchema.DB_IS_ALARM_SCHEDULED + " = " + passAlarmScheduledStatus, null);
}
```

and then extract

```
 //common operation for all,
public static List<NoteModel> extractCommonData(Cursor cursor, List<NoteModel> noteModelList) {
    noteModelList = new ArrayList<>();

    if (LOG_DEBUG) Log.i(TAG, "inside extractCommonData()");
    if (cursor != null) {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                NoteModel noteModel = new NoteModel();

                noteModel.set_id(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBSchema.DB_ROW_ID)));
                noteModel.setTitle(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBSchema.DB_TITLE)));
                noteModel.setImgUriPath(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBSchema.DB_IMAGE_PATH)));
                noteModel.setSub_text(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBSchema.DB_SUB_TEXT)));
                noteModel.setCreateDate(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBSchema.DB_CREATE_DATE)));
                noteModel.setUpdateDate(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBSchema.DB_UPDATE_DATE)));
                noteModel.setScheduleTimeLong(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBSchema.DB_SCHEDULED_TIME_LONG)));
                noteModel.setScheduledWhenLong(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBSchema.DB_SCHEDULED_TIME_WHEN)));
                noteModel.setScheduledTitle(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBSchema.DB_SCHEDULED_TITLE)));
                noteModel.setIsAlarmScheduled(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBSchema.DB_IS_ALARM_SCHEDULED)));
                noteModel.setIsTaskDone(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBSchema.DB_IS_TASK_DONE)));
                noteModel.setIsArchived(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBSchema.DB_IS_ARCHIVED)));
                noteModelList.add(noteModel);

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();

    }
    return noteModelList;
}
```

Again, I din't read,just copied from my old samples
Please do find the needful, cheers